# Can I run a single test in a suite?

Tags: go, testify

I have setup a test suite for my struct (https://github.com/stretchr/testify#suite-package). Before I was able to run a single test by specifying just a pattern:

```
go test -v ./services/gateways/... -run mytest
```

This approach doesn't work after conversion. Bad luck or is there a way?

Comment: Does `-m` do what you expect? From the documentation: `Regular expression to select the methods of test suites specified command-line argument "-m"` maybe combined with `-run` to specify the suite?

Comment: According to help, "`run` is to  - Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression." The content of the file only has one test that calls the suite method. So `go test` after analyzing files may just not find matches if it looks for something like `func TestBlah(t *testing.T)`...

Comment: yes, `-run` picks the `Test*` function to run, which starts a particular suite, and the `-m` flag will filter which suite methods to execute.

Answer (score 21):

You can run single methods by specifying the `-testify.m` argument.

to run [this suite method](https://github.com/vektra/mockery/blob/b6f6c13c25c3f0a17724553fa01580f328158d7a/mockery/generator_test.go#L104-L132) the command is:

`go test -v github.com/vektra/mockery/mockery -run ^TestGeneratorSuite$ -testify.m TestGenerator`

Comment: Now the flag has been changed to -m (go version go1.9)

Comment: It's a shame that you can't just mark a test with .only or something like you can do in other test frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

i think you're SOL with that package but here's a similar approach with go 1.7's stock testing tools:

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestSuite1(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("first test", func(t *testing.T) { t.Fail() })
    t.Run("second test", func(t *testing.T) { t.Fail() })
}

func TestSuite2(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("third test", func(t *testing.T) { t.Fatal("3") })
    t.Run("fourth test", func(t *testing.T) { t.Fatal("4") })
}
```

Example output for one suite:

```
 therealplato/stack-suites Ω go test -run TestSuite1       
--- FAIL: TestSuite1 (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestSuite1/first_test (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestSuite1/second_test (0.00s)
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/therealplato/stack-suites    0.005s
```

Example output for one test:

```
 therealplato/stack-suites Ω go test -run TestSuite2/third 
--- FAIL: TestSuite2 (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestSuite2/third_test (0.00s)
        main_test.go:11: 3
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/therealplato/stack-suites    0.005s
```

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps `TestSuite2/third` is the key. I'll try. Thank you!